# Error 91 setting range of worksheet variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm at a loss as to why it seems that I can store a range value in the range property of a worksheet variable but not in a range variable. I got error 91 every time I tried to run this code:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.name = "Potato"
    rng = ws.Range("A1:K1")
    rng.PasteSpecial
```

I was able to run the program successfully by replacing the last 2 lines with:

```
    ws.Range("A1:K1").PasteSpecial
```

This works, even though it clutters other parts of my code. But I can't understand for the life of me what the problem was with using the range variable was.

I would appreciate any clarification anyone can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Set` with object variables:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:K1")
```

Comment: Makes sense. Never would have occurred to me that a range is an object while worksheets and workbooks aren't. Thanks!

Comment: Worksheets and workbooks are also objects. What makes you think they aren't?

Answer (score 0):

Here is added code that will make sure there won't be an error if you already have a sheet named "Potato"

Code to make sure Sheet("Potato") doesn't already exist.

```
   Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, cRng As Range
    Dim worksh As Integer
    Dim worksheetexists As Boolean
    Dim s As String

    s = "Potato"
    Set cRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K1")

    worksh = Application.Sheets.Count
    worksheetexists = False

    For x = 1 To worksh

        If Worksheets(x).Name = s Then
            worksheetexists = True
            MsgBox s & ", already Exists"
            Exit For
        End If

    Next x

    If worksheetexists = False Then
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add()
        ws.Name = s
        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:K1")

        cRng.Copy
        rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'd gone with the copy/paste method to preserve a myriad of formatting I won't be able to predict. Is there an efficient way to do that with your approach? Or must one set every conceivable property of the new range to match the old one?

Comment: If it works for you then Okay, I changed the code so if you run it and "Potato" already exists, you won't get an error.